# HTML Parsing Exception in java code org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, dom, saxparser

I am trying to read a .html file by DOM parser but it gives me following exception while parsing.

```
[Fatal Error] form3.html:559:133: The element type "font" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</font>".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/puja/Dnyaneshwar/WCD_14_02_17/FileConverter/resources/form3.html; lineNumber: 559; columnNumber: 133; The element type "font" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</font>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:347)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:205)
    at DomConverter.main(DomConverter.java:25)
```

Comment: the error is clear you have an open `<font>` tag without closed `</font>` try to fix it

Comment: Actually, I converted doc file to an HTML by Libre office. Here I solved lots of issue like above by manually editing the file but that file is so much big. So can we disable such checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use an XML parser to parse an HTML document not even an xhtml document.

You can use an html parser like jsoup.